# Opengles image texture preloading on iOS

Tags: ios, core-animation, opengl-es-2.0, avfoundation, calayer

I am creating a photo slide show with complex transitions between images on iOS. Core Animation doesn't suits the purpose as the possible transitions are limited, so I resort to Opengles 2.0. The problem is uploading images to GPU and creating texture is a time consuming operation & takes roughly 200 ms even for a 960x640 image, which is not suitable for real time playback scenario. And its not feasible to pre-create all the textures before hand as there could be 100s of them. I wonder how Core Animation deals with this problem and is smooth enough to run no matter how many CGImages you assign in animations ? (As long as images are presented at different times and not together).

Comment: You want to change slides more than 5 times per second? Or is it just the latency you worry about? The common strategy for this kind of problem is to load one or two slides ahead of what you're currently displaying. So once you need the image for a slide the first time, it's already loaded. You can look at it like a cache of slides, where you pre-fetch entries that you are going to need soon.

Comment: Yes its the latency I am worried about. Its supposed to run on AVPlayer as a video so latency requirements would be tight. I just need to understand the best approach to handle it, particularly when you seek across the video composition, images would come & go back too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Texture loading is time consuming and most of applications dealing with a large number of them are loading them on some initialisation. That is the simplest approach but surely most resource consuming. You must understand that what goes on in the back is reading an image file, decompressing it, creating a raw RGB(A) data on the CPU, allocating a memory on the GPU and sending the raw data to the GPU...

As the best approach of dealing with large number of textures is loading them in background preferably even before you need them. In your case as already mentioned in the comment you will need to create some smart cache of these textures. This will still not be enough since the loading itself might make your thread unresponsive. You will need to add a background task to handle those images.

What I suggest to you is creating 2 additional threads. First should load the image data to the CPU while the second will push the data to the GPU. The first thread is pretty straight forward while the second will need a bit of additional GL code to accomplish. Each thread will need its own openGL context to be able to communicate with the GPU, so once you create this thread you also need to create an extra context. These contexts are not aware of each others resources which leads to creating a texture in one context will make it unusable on the other context. For this you will need an extra parameter called a share group. So first you create the share group and then create both contexts with the same share group so the textures will be accessible. Do note that the context is preferably created on the thread you are supposed to be using it on (it might be enough to simply set it as current though).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am thinking of using AVCustomCompositor to create the effects & transitions to run on AVPlayer in real time. User can seek quickly across the video which would mean images quickly coming & going. In addition, I must be able to predict that a new image is about to be played in the next 0.5 seconds or so and start fetching it. But if the user seeks the video I must discard the old textures and fetch new ones. Seems a lot of work, probably Core Animation is doing something along these lines.